# Tourist cell phone use in Myanmar

Tags: cellphones, myanmar

Most countries allow you to purchase SIMS at the airport for cell phone use in the country. Can you do this in Yangon airport (RGN)?

Comment: Some pretty exhaustive infos on http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Myanmar

Comment: Yes, and we found the info on the site @Adrien mentions to be accurate when we were there in December 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could buy SIM card at the Yangon International Airport as soon as you arrive. Or you could even find it near the shore of the Airport. Most of they sell are **

> Ooredoo, Telenor and MPT

**. All sim price are under $2 dollar. You could get free over 1 hours from Ooredoo and Telenor as soon as you buy them. But those Ooredoo and Telenor are not supported the whole country. To be able to communicate the whole country, you should buy MPT. That's all what I know

Answer (score 5):

Yes there are booths from mobile providers at the airport.  You can also get SIMs at mobile shops in the city.

Comment: Any idea on price?

Comment: @Will may you give us some price info after your trip to Myanmar?

Comment: I forgot the price, but it was not much.